# Contact form not communicating with my mail server, whats up?

Tags: javascript, css, forms, contacts

Really odd here...would like others to look aswell...thank you.

Here's the HTML I'm using:

```
<div id="contactform">
            <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate action="" class="popup-form">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-white" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Full Name">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-white" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Email Address">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-white" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Phone Number">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-white" id="reach" name="reach" placeholder="Best Form of Contact">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-white" id="attendees" name="attendees" placeholder="Number of Guests">
                <input type="text" id="overnight"  name="overnight" class="form-control form-white" placeholder="Number of Overnight Guests">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-white" id="event" name="event" placeholder="Type of Event">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-white" id="meals" name="meals" placeholder="Meals included?">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-white" id="date" name="date" placeholder="Date Desired (ex. 4/16-4/25)">
                <input type="text" rows="10" cols="100" class="form-control form-white" id="message" name="message" placeholder="More Info">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-submit">Submit</button>
                <div id="success"></div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

And here's the JS.

```
    <?php
// check if fields passed are empty
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])       ||
   empty($_POST['email'])       ||
   empty($_POST['message']) ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
    echo "No arguments Provided!";
    return false;
   }

$message = "Name: " . $_POST['name'];
$message .= "\r\nPhone " . $_POST['phone'];
$message .= "\r\nEmail: " . $_POST['email'];
$message .= "\r\nRequested Form of Contact: " . $_POST['reach'];
$message .= "\r\nEvent Type: " . $_POST['event'];
$message .= "\r\nRequested Dates: " . $_POST['date'];
$message .= "\r\nNumber of Attendees: " . $_POST['attendees'];
$message .= "\r\nOvernight Guests: " . $_POST['overnight'];
$message .= "\r\nMeals Included?: " . $_POST['meals'];
$message .= "\r\nAdditional Information: " . $_POST['message'];




$to = 'fakeemailforprivacy@gmail.com'; 
$email_subject = "Wahnee Events Inquiry"; 
$email_body = $message;
$headers = "From: inquiry@wahneeevents.com\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";                                                                                                                                           
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

Yes it is linked in through my HTML (the JS file)
Not quite sure what the problem is though, as it worked with an old contact form, I literally just copied and pasted it...hmm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-submit">Submit</button>
```

to

```
<button action="submit" class="btn btn-submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: That didn't do the trick, it submits, but I get the error I have my JS say "trouble communicating with mail server" Thank you!